# Как из первого фрейма проверить загрузилась ли страница во втором?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице фреймсет из 2х фреймов.
Как из первого фрейма javascript'ом (или же jQuery) проверить прогрузилась ли полностью страница во втором фрейме?
Цель: выполнить функцию в первом фрейме после того, как страница во втором фрейме отгрузится.

Comment: это, конечно не красиво с моей стороны, но помню месяц назад тут попадалась мне на глаза подобная тема. посмотрите на хэшкоде в поиске

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.document
```

это ссылка на родительскую страницу, код вызывать в первом фрейме.

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("айди_второго_фрейма")...<действия со вторым фреймом>
```

это уже для работы со вторым фреймом из первого

Comment: а как именно проверить из первого фрейма, что страница во втором фрейме отгружена полностью, и если отгружена полностью, то выполнить определенную функцию?

Comment: window.parent.onload = function() {...} не?

Comment: Установить во втором фрейме событие онлоад, и в этом событии устанавливать какой-то флаг, например, в родительской странице

Comment: а если нет врзможности изменять код страницы прогружаемой во втором фрейме?

Comment: Тогда проверяйте контент во фрейме и анализируйте его.
http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=671121